# per-task data structure in linux kernel module

Tags: c, linux, data-structures, linux-kernel

I am writing a loadable kernel module for Linux. And I need to store some data for each task in Linux kernel (These data would be used in a scheduler callback).

I know that I can modify `struct task_struct` and insert my own fields. But since I am willing to write a relatively **clean** kernel module, I cannot modify any code resides in original Linux source tree.

It is also possible to maintain some sort of mapping from `struct task_struct` to my data in a hash table. But it seem to be a little too heavy-weight.

I've read the answer in [Thread local data in linux kernel module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402330/thread-local-data-in-linux-kernel-module). It mentioned using `private_data` in `struct file`. But it needs every thread to open it in order to get an `struct file`. And there's no way the query the per-task data with a `struct task_struct`. (As I need to use the data in a scheduler callback)

My question is: is there any simple and clean way that allows me registering per-task data-structure in Linux kernel without modifying `struct task_struct`?

Many thanks!

Comment: What is that per-task data and what is your module really doing? Explain much more!

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch I need to store some data for each `task_struct` in kernel. And during scheduling these data might be accessed. Imagine that I am writing a module that counts #context-switch for each thread (I know this functionality exists in original kernel so it's just an example. It's difficult to explain what my module really doing here clearly in a few words.)

Comment: @Naruil: you have a whole question to say this. Very few kernel modules really need to keep track of per-process data; if you can say why this is needed, it will make it clearer how to proceed.

Comment: @nneonneo Ok, let me make it clearer. This module implements a high-performance kernel-assisted sync mechanism for user programs. Each user thread would register a data structure to kernel. And this data structure may be accessed in kernel space by a scheduler callback function and some sync primitives it exposed via a device. So do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only simple and clean way that allows you to register a per-task data structure is to modify `struct task_struct`.

Modules are designed for *optional* parts of the kernel; they can use only functions that are explicitly exported from the base kernel.
if you have to change the base kernel, you can no longer use modules.